# Loading a 3D Cubes from an array saved on a .txt File

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, file-io, 3d, cube

i'm still at a intermediate level when it comes to coding, so please excuse any anything that doesn't quite sound right.

I have created an array within a .txt file called "cube". I have a body of code I've been working on and it is partially completed, but I'm just wondering, does it look like it will function how intended, with loading the information from the file and how exactly I would load "Color" and "Indices" information, as commented at the bottom of the code.

```
bool Cube::Load(char* path)
{

    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(path);
    if (!inFile.good())
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't open text file" << path << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    inFile >> numVertices;
    indexedVertices = new Vertex[numVertices];
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
        //TODO use inFile to populate the indexedVertices array
        ifstream inputFile;
        inputFile.open("cube.txt");

    }

    //TO DO: Load Color information

    //TO DO: Load Indices information


    inFile.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I say this depends on information that is missing from the question.

Comment: You should try to solve it yourself and then come back if you can't, with code, sample input and expected output, if it applies.

Comment: Question is rather vague. That parts that's confusing me about your code is that you have two input files, but there's no mention of that in your description. Is that a mistake or just something you didn't tell us about?

Comment: The other strange thing about your code, almost definitely a mistake, is that you are opening "cube.txt" repeatedly. I see no good reason for that.

Comment: Why don't you hardcode the vertex data of the cube?